# HTML positioning with more items

Tags: html, css

I'm sort of new to HTML and currently, I am creating a custom home page for myself containing links to site I often visit.

When I hover over a picture it expands to show more specific links (i.e. subreddits).

However, the problem is that the "sub-link-icons" are not properly aligned with the expanding DIV It will show in front of the bigger picture when hovering over it.

**What I am trying to do is have the sub-link-icons to be in sync with the expanding div.***

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="submenu" id="steam"><a href="http://store.steampowered.com" target="_blank"><img src="steam.png"></a></div>
        <div class="submenu" id="reddit">
            <a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="reddit.png"/></a>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="reddit.png"/></li>
                <li><img src="reddit.png"/></li>
                <li><img src="reddit.png"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="submenu" id="youtube"><a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src="youtube.png"/></a></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #330000;
    color: white;
}

div img {
    width:256px;
    height:256px;
    border-radius:5px;
}

li img {
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    border-radius:15px;
}

#youtube:hover {
    border: #E6E6E6 solid 4px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

#steam:hover {
    border: #12151A solid 4px;
    background-color: #12151A;
}

#g2a:hover {
    border: #0F1F2E solid 4px;
    background-color: #0F1F2E;
}

#reddit:hover {
    border: #999999 solid 4px;
    background-color: #999999;
}

ul{
    position:absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    display:none;
    margin-left: 125px;
}

.submenu {
    border-radius: 5px;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width:256px;
    height:256px;
    border:4px solid #330000;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    transition: width 1s;
    z-index:0;
}

.submenu img {
    float:left;
}

.submenu:hover {
    width:350px;
    transition: width 1s;
}

.submenu:hover img {
    float:left;
    z-index:2;
}

.submenu ul {
    position: absolute;
}

.submenu:hover ul {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-left:-45px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.submenu:hover ul li img {
    float:left;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: 12.5px;
}
```

I've tried searching the web for help but couldn't quite manage it.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/eehdo8wa/1/)

Comment: please specify how do you want the sublink-icons to show

Comment: Sorry if being unclear. I want them to be behind the bigger link picture and slide out in sync with the div expanding when you mouse over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets go through this step by step.

**First issue: On hover, "sub-icon-links" are layered over your big pictures, instead of under it.**

This IS fixable with z-index, but first you have to understand how z-index works.

**Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).**

With z-index you can layer elements that are in the same HTML layer. Because it didn't work I assume you've tried to apply z-index on the sub-menu-links. This wouldn't work because the big picture is not on the same layer as them. If we take a look at your HTML structure you'll see:

```
<div class="submenu" id="reddit">
        <a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.workatplay.com/files/styles/fpo_medium/public/article/logo/Reddit%20Small.jpg?itok=dclAuuiP"/></a>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://www.workatplay.com/files/styles/fpo_medium/public/article/logo/Reddit%20Small.jpg?itok=dclAuuiP"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.workatplay.com/files/styles/fpo_medium/public/article/logo/Reddit%20Small.jpg?itok=dclAuuiP"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.workatplay.com/files/styles/fpo_medium/public/article/logo/Reddit%20Small.jpg?itok=dclAuuiP"/></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

To use z-index in this case, you have to see at which points the images or their containers are on the same layer.

- Your big image is contained within an anchor tag (a)
- Your small images are contained within list items
- These list items are contained within an unordered list

This unordered list and the anchor tag are on the same layer. Applying z-index to one of these will fix this issue.

Note: This works different when using things like "position: absolute" and "position: fixed" or any other attribute that changes the position of the element in the HTML stack.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eehdo8wa/5/

What I did:

1. Added "z-index: -1;" to ".submenu ul"
2. Removed "z-index: 1;" from ".submenu:hover ul"

**Second issue: On hover, the "sub-icon-links" should expand at the same rate as the div expands**

So, doing this should be very simple now the pictures are layered under the big picture correctly. Basically, when you think about it, all you should have to do is make the pictures stick to the right side of its parent, so when it expands, the pictures stick to the right side and slide along, taking them into the view.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eehdo8wa/6/

What I did:

I redid some of the CSS to make it so everything is already in the right position before sliding into the view. This is essentially what you want in these cases. In your original fiddle you had a LOT of styling on the hover portions, changing all kinds of styling and spacings, but was it really needed? In the end, no. Now it's all in position behind the big image, ready to slide right into the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! :)